# opption menu Jelly bean

Tags: java, android, menu

How will it be possible to have a menu button which call option-menus with the following condistions ( must be ):

- App hides the titlebar :

  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
- the targetversion in Manifest is set to 16 :

  ```
  android:targetSdkVersion="16"
  ```

Some Infos and researches from my side:
Setting targetSdkVersion="10" shows the menu still in the bottom, which I would like to achieve. 
Showing the titlebar shows the menubutton in top ( 3 points icon ) and the menu is also callable. But I need to hide the titlebar.

any hints , suggestions ?

thanks & regards
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use slider menu and have it on left or right. You shouldn't include button on action bar (like facebook), you can open menu after item click or onFling event.

There is nice and easy tutorial that I tried:

http://oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Facebook-Style-Slide-Menu-In-Android